# How to push to an array that is iterated by ng-repeat from within a controller?

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here's Angular’s behavior I had no idea about.

Let’s say I have an array of items in the controller, and I ng-repeat through them in the view. I have a button in the view, and when I click on it, an item is pushed in the array. The ng-repeated list gets updated in the view. All’s good so far.

**But.**
If I just push a new item in the array inside the controller (let’s say, I set a timeout to do so), ng-repeat in the view will not register the change of the array.

Example on plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1mlOpGVOXmnCAa8W5KEx?p=preview

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/angular.js/1.4.0-beta.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <main ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
      <button ng-click="ctrl.addName()">Add an item</button>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in ctrl.names">
          {{name.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', function(){
    var self = this;

    self.test = 2;
    self.names = [{name: 'example'}];

    self.addName = function(){
      self.names.push({name: 'new example'});
      console.log(self.names)
    };

    setTimeout(function(){
      self.names.push({name: 'another example'});
      console.log(self.names);
    }, 1000);

  });
```

Observed behavior: clicking on the button will trigger the `addName` function and add an item to the list. `setTimeout` however will push an item in the array, but that won't be reflected in the view. While examining the results of the console log, I see that the items that are displayed have a `$$hashKey` property, and a simple push to the array will result in an item that lacks this property.

**Question:**  What is the proper way for adding items to an array in the controller? Should I use $digest or $apply or something?

Comment: `setTimeout` was given as an example of a function called from within a controller. My actual code responds to an event that's fired in the controller and pushes an item to the array.

Comment: how will that function trigger? if you calling by hand, you still need to wrap inside something like, $timeout or  $applyAsync or $evalAsync or $$postDigest. if you call it from $http.get, it will trigger automatically.

Comment: I am using a third-party geomapping library. It returns a promise, and I am calling a function in the controller when this  promise is resolved. The function will then add whatever the promise returned to the `this.names` array on the controller. But the angular context is lost, apparently. So I am wondering how to restore it.

Comment: yes, thats not angular's promise, so, you need to trigger it manually with one of the above I mentioned. (eg., `$scope.$applyAsync(function(){self.names.push({name: 'another example'});});`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular works by periodically performing dirty checks if any of the watched model values has changed. It does that in so-called `$digest` cycles. These cycles are automatically run when Angular thinks it is necessary, but if an event happens outside the Angular context, Angular will not know about it, will not fire a `$digest` cycle, won't detect the change(s) and the view will not be updated.

When you push a value to an array (outside the Angular context), you will need to run the $digest cycle manually, e.g. by wrapping your function into `$scope.evalAsync()`, which will trigger dirty checking in scope.

**Update:** Yes, you can also call `$scope.$digest()`, but the problem with that is that if $digest cycle is already running, you will get that unfamous *"$digest() already in progress"* error.

`$scope.evalAsync()` does not suffer from that problem, because it fires a `$digest` cycle asynchronously. What's more, if a `$digest` cycle is already in progress, it will try to do the work in this same cycle and will not unnecessarily fire a new one.

You can also see this [excellent blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm) by Ben Nadel, explaining everything in even more details (e.g. comparison with using the `$timeout` service, which is yet another alternative).

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment, I am not using `setTimeout` in my actual code — I am listening to events fired by a certain object and then run a function that pushes an element to the array. The `setTimeout` I used in the question is just for illustration purposes. So I am looking for a general solution, not the specific one that will just deal with `setTimeout`.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will update my answer accordingly. The answer is basically the same, you need to fire a $digest cycle manually when an event happens outside Angular.

Comment: And how do I fire the $digest cycle manually? Is it something like `self.names.$digest()`?

Comment: Almost. :) It's `$scope.$digest()` (or `$scope.$apply()`), but that has some downsides(i'll further update my answer)

Comment: Ah, I wanted to use the `controller as` syntax and try to stay clear of the `$scope`. But this works, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you.